# How to store the dropdown, other option text input data in database using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do have a select dropdown and in that few options also and in that OTHERS option also

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="mainone">
        <%#= form.text_field :city, placeholder: "CITY", class: 'form-control required' %>
        <%= form.select :city, options_for_select([['DELHI'],['GURGAON'],['FARIDABAD'],['GHAZIABAD'],['NOIDA'],['MUMBAI'],['THANE'], ['BANGALORE'],['OTHERS']]), {include_blank: 'CITY*'}, class: 'form-control required', name: 'city', :onchange => 'Checkselectedone(this.value);' %>
            <% if @ezetab.errors[:city].present? %>
                <span class="error_msg"><%= @ezetab.errors[:city][0]%></span>
            <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <%= form.text_field :city, name: 'city', id: 'newtext', label: "Others",style: 'display:none;' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

> when i select the others option one more text box should come and i
>   can type which is my city.
>
> but the thing is here that entered city data also should be store in
>   the same filed. but i dont no how to save that one in the same field.
>
> these are the my fields

```
def ezetab_params
        params.require(:ezetab).permit(:name, :email, :phonenumber, :organization, :city)
    end
```

> this is javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Checkselectedone(val){
    alert("one more text box is coming");
 var element=document.getElementById('newtext');
 if(val=='OTHERS')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script>

can any one tell me how to store that other option data also in the same city filed and i have give required also for that it should not be shown any validation msg. please let me know.
thanks in advance
```

Comment: do you want to store more than one datas in one field?
can you give and example?

Comment: sure see in the drop down i have some cities like bangalore, delhi, chennai, others. if i select the other one more text box is appearing and in that ill write city which is not there in the drop down that one is need to be store in the same city field. i have given presence: true for all the fields, and i am trying that from more 4 hours to save but each time getting fail.

Comment: i have given a solution, hope it helped you.

Comment: hi it is working when i select the other option and it is storing also. but from the drop down existing city i am unable to store. each time getting validation error like city cant be blank.

Comment: hi Gabbar, see it is working in one case like if i chouse the other option then it is working and storing also. apart from other if i select the city which is present in the drop sown then it is giving... CITY cant be blank.

Comment: Hi gabbar, now it is storing only OTHERS one only which I am entering the city in another text box this is correct... And I need one more case that is if I select the city which is present in drop-down that is not storing, saying that city can't be empty, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check on controller side , whether city params are coming from dropdown list, use pry or debugger at controller.

Comment: i am not getting the drop down selected one dont no where it is going wrong

Comment: i got your issue here, its cause you should not specify `name: 'city'` with `form.select :city` cause of this city value is not submitted with form data , which are selected with form, so please have a look, i made slight change and it will help you, please let me know for further guidance. :)

Comment: here other option filed data is not storing. it saving in the filed just like others.. city name which i am texting is not storing. please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158919/discussion-between-gabbar-and-rocker).

Comment: Working fine Thanks a lot. if u dont mind can i have your mail-id because i new to ruby on rails in my company i am the only person is here, so only please share me your details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="mainone">
        <%#= form.text_field :city, placeholder: "CITY", class: 'form-control required' %>
        <%= form.select :city, options_for_select([['DELHI'],['GURGAON'],['FARIDABAD'],['GHAZIABAD'],['NOIDA'],['MUMBAI'],['THANE'], ['BANGALORE'],['OTHERS']]), {include_blank: 'CITY*'}, class: 'form-control required', :onchange => 'Checkselectedone(this.value);' %>
            <% if @ezetab.errors[:city].present? %>
                <span class="error_msg"><%= @ezetab.errors[:city][0]%></span>
            <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <%= text_field_tag :others, "", class: 'form-control', id: 'newtext', style: 'display:none;' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller: -

```
def ezetab_params
   ep = params.require(:ezetab).permit(:name, :email, :phonenumber, :organization, :city)
   ep[:city] = params[:others] if params[:others].present?
   ep            
end
```

Comment: `<%= form.select :city, options_for_select([['DELHI'],['GURGAON'],['FARIDABAD'],['GHAZIABAD'],['NOIDA'],['MUMBAI'],['THANE'], ['BANGALORE'],['OTHERS']]), {include_blank: 'CITY*'}, class: 'form-control required', :onchange => 'Checkselectedone(this.value);' %>` check this new code line